# CircleCI docker compose permission denied?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, circleci

I am trying to use docker compose in circle ci so that I can run some component tests in as a step in my workflow. But when I try to use docker compose I get this error: `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`/

Here is my circle ci config

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
  component_test:
    docker:
    - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
    working_directory: ~/repo
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Install Docker Compose
        command: |
          curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.19.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/docker-compose
          chmod +x ~/docker-compose
          sudo mv ~/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - setup_remote_docker:
        docker_layer_caching: true
    - run: |
        set -x
        docker ps
        docker-compose up -d
    - run: |
        ./gradlew cucumber -Dtag="@Local"
```

Output: 
    ====>> sudo groupadd docker
      #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
    sudo groupadd docker
    ====>> sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
      #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
    sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
    Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

```
Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                him/her from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -v, --add-subuids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate uids
  -V, --del-subuids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate uids
  -w, --add-subgids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate gids
  -W, --del-subgids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate gids
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     new SELinux user mapping for the user account

Error: Exited with code 2
Step failed
Error: runner failed
{"Runner":true,"level":"error","msg":"runner failed","task-id":"localbuild-1547728937","time":"2019-01-17T12:42:24Z"}
Task failed
Error: task failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.If you don’t want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group.

To create the `docker` group and add your user:

1. Create the `docker` group.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

2. Add your user to the `docker` group.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

   If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the virtual machine for changes to take effect.

   On a desktop Linux environment such as X Windows, log out of your session completely and then log back in.
4. Verify that you can run `docker` commands without `sudo`.

```
$ docker ps
```